# How to compare two lists with out order

Tags: list, c#-4.0

I have two lists.

Ex:

```
    List<string> expected = new List<string>();

    expected.Add( "a" );
    expected.Add( "b" );
    expected.Add( "c" );


    actual = new List<string>();
    actual.Add( "c" );
    actual.Add( "a" );
    actual.Add( "b" );
    actual.Add( "e" );
    actual.Add( "d" );
```

I have to compare both lists(regardless order).i have to remove extra values what are in the
second list.if second list contain all values of first list then i have to return true.

Can you please give any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:  I'm not clear on your statement "i have to remove extra values what are in the second list" but i think I'm understanding that you just want the union of both lists.  Am I right?

```
        var expected = new List<string>();
        expected.Add("a");
        expected.Add("b");
        expected.Add("c");

        var actual = new List<string>();
        actual.Add("c");
        actual.Add("a");
        actual.Add("b");
        actual.Add("e");
        actual.Add("d");

        // sort the lists
        expected.Sort();
        actual.Sort();

        // if the lists are equal return true;
        if (expected.SequenceEqual(actual))
        {
            // the lists have the same contents -- return true or whatever
        }
        else {
            // union of both lists (abcde)
            var unionOfBoth = expected.Union(actual).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Is SequenceEqual method consider order ?

Comment: Thanks for help.I used this this method:(Not Union method)..I have to use Intersect method                                var unionOfBoth = expected.Intersect(actual).ToList();

Comment: Sorry yes - I added the explicit .Sort() on the lists before calling SequenceEqual :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is this a homework? ;-)

implement a bool function and define a `bool equal = true;` in the first line.

At first, you should determine which of the lists is bigger. If they don't have the same size, set the `bool equal`-Variable to false as they connot be equal.

Then you iterate over the bigger one(or any of the two if they have the same size) and check if the current element of iteration is in the list via `actual.Contains()`. AFAIK string lists check if there is an element equal to the element to check in the list.

If this check is false for the smaller list, remove the current element from the bigger list as ist is not contained in the other. Also set the `bool equal`-Variable to false, as the lists cannot be equal anymore.

return the `equal` Variable.